# Printing array elements

Tags: c, arrays

The expected output of the following C program is to print the array elements. But when actually run, it doesn't do so.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))

int array[] = {23,34,12,17,204,99,16};

int main()
{
    int d;

    for(d=-1;d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2);d++)
        printf("%d\n",array[d+1]);

    return 0;
}
```

What is the reason ?

Comment: Why not simply `for (d = 0; d < TOTAL_ELEMENTS; ++d)`?

Comment: Maybe it's an instructive example of how difficult it is to program correctly in C. And in view of that, it is indeed a very good example.

Comment: This question is part of [Gowri Korumar's C puzzles](http://www.gowrikumar.com/c/), a compilation of 50 very educational C questions. I answered the first 25 questions both from past knowledge and research, in case it helps: [C puzzles answered](http://codeitdown.com/c-puzzles-answered/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do the comparison `d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2)`, a **type conversion** is performed. `d` is of type `signed int` while `(TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2)` is of type `size_t`, which is an unsigned type. The rules of C say that when an operator has a signed and an unsigned argument, and the unsigned argument is of greater or equal size to the signed argument, then the signed argument is converted to unsigned.

That is, the comparison ends up as:

```
(size_t) d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2)
```

And because `size_t` is unsigned, `(size_t) -1` is a really, really large number, not -1 any more. For a 32-bit `size_t` it would be 2<sup>32</sup> - 1 = 4,294,967,295.

To fix this, you can explicitly cast the right-hand side to signed int:

```
d <= (int) (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2)
```

Or, better, just get rid of the weird negative indexing and such.

For future reference, turn on all the **compiler warnings** you can. gcc, for instance, will print a warning if you turn on `-Wall -Wextra`:

```
$ gcc -o arrayprint -Wall -Wextra -ansi arrayprint.c 
arrayprint.c: In function ‘main’:
arrayprint.c:11: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
```

Comment: other than casting the result of the macro to `int`, it would be much simpler to use `size_t` for `d` from the start and to use proper bounds `0` for the start and `d < TOTAL_ELEMENTS` for the condition.

Answer (score 6):

`TOTAL_ELEMENTS` is unsigned.  -1, when converted to unsigned, is a really huge number, which is not less than 6.  Thus, your loop never runs.

Comment: Yep... you should never mix signed / unsigned assignments or comparison without a proper reason and in that case an explicit casting is in place. Also, most compilers should have issued a warning for this if the appropriate warning level was set.

Answer (score 3):

At first, I didn't know. But when I compiled it using GCC, it was obviously apparent:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Os a.c
a.c: In function `main':
a.c:11: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
```

So you have a comparison as follows:

```
(int) -1 <= (size_t) 5
```

Since one of the types is signed and the other is unsigned, they first need to be converted to a common type. In this case, it is `size_t`. That makes it:

```
(size_t) -1 <= (size_t) 5
```

Now `-1` cannot be represented in an unsigned type. Therefore, 2^32 (or however many bits `size_t` has) is added to it, which makes it 4294967295. So the comparison really is:

```
4294967295 <= 5
```

And that's `false`, therefore the loop body is never executed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the loop is never executed. This is because `TOTAL_ELEMENTS` returns a size_t, an unsigned type.

You can fix this by casting `(TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2)` to an int.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

```
for(d=0;d < TOTAL_ELEMENTS;d++)
    printf("%d\n",array[d]);
```

as `sizeof(...)` produces an unsigned value.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change

```
#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
```

With

```
#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (int)(sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))-2
```

Comment: you really take it at the wrong end. Array indices should always just be `size_t`. He just should change `d` to be of `size_t` and do a proper indexing and all the fuzz goes away...